# Elegantly Toggling Many Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

Let's say I have a handful of functions that do things:

```
function doStuff()  { console.log('doing stuff'); }
function doThings() { console.log('doing things'); }
function doIt()     { console.log('doing it'); }
function doThis()   { console.log('doing this'); }
function doThat()   { console.log('doing that'); }
```

And then just as many that disable their behaviors:

```
function stopStuff()  { console.log('stopping stuff'); }
function stopThings() { console.log('stopping things'); }
function stopIt()     { console.log('stopping it'); }
function stopThis()   { console.log('stopping this'); }
function stopThat()   { console.log('stopping that'); }
```

Then I put all the 'do' functions in an object so I can dynamically access them by setting `what`:

```
var what = 'things';

var doing = {
    stuff:  function() { doStuff(); },
    things: function() { doThings(); },
    it:     function() { doIt(); },
    this:   function() { doThis(); },
    that:   function() { doThat(); }
};

doing[what](); //console logs 'doing things'
```

Is there a way to go about enabling one `do` function while iterating through all the non-matching `stop` functions?

For example, if I do `var what = 'this'; doing[what]();`, I want it to not only `doThis();` but also `stopStuff(); stopThings(); stopIt(); stopThat();`

I'm having trouble coming up with an elegant method that doesn't involve lengthy if statements or case/switch.

Comment: I'd do a function, something like stopDoing(noThis) and if this function has noThis parameter set, it'd call every stop function and not the one on the parameter. and if no parameter is set, it'll call all stop functions... something like that!

Comment: How about stopping all the functions and after that starting the desired one.

Comment: Almost certainly an XY question. Do you mind sharing the reason why you'd need something like this? What do these things start and stop, what determines if they need to be started or stopped?

Comment: @Amadan They're controlling various animation effects.

Comment: Without more details, I'd probably have an array of objects of the form `{ name: "Stuff", on: function() { ... }, off: function() { ... } }`, then just loop over them and running `effect.on()` or `effect.off()` depending if it matches your criterion or not. But again, not enough details; I dislike the idea that they are just functions thrown randomly into the global context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your do/stop functions are global - this works

```js
function doStuff()  { console.log('doing stuff'); }
function doThings() { console.log('doing things'); }
function doIt()     { console.log('doing it'); }
function doThis()   { console.log('doing this'); }
function doThat()   { console.log('doing that'); }

function stopStuff()  { console.log('stopping stuff'); };
function stopThings() { console.log('stopping things'); };
function stopIt()     { console.log('stopping it'); };
function stopThis()   { console.log('stopping this'); };
function stopThat()   { console.log('stopping that'); };


var run = function(root) {
    var fnNames = ['stuff', 'things', 'it', 'this', 'that'];
    return function(what) {
        fnNames.forEach(function (fn) {
            var fnName = fn[0].toUpperCase() + fn.slice(1);
            root[(what == fn ? 'do' : 'stop') + fnName]();
        });
    };
}(window);
// usage
console.log('things');
run('things');
console.log('this');
run('this');
```

However, if they are not global, it's a little messier, but not by much

```js
function doStuff()  { console.log('doing stuff'); }
function doThings() { console.log('doing things'); }
function doIt()     { console.log('doing it'); }
function doThis()   { console.log('doing this'); }
function doThat()   { console.log('doing that'); }

function stopStuff()  { console.log('stopping stuff'); }
function stopThings() { console.log('stopping things'); }
function stopIt()     { console.log('stopping it'); }
function stopThis()   { console.log('stopping this'); }
function stopThat()   { console.log('stopping that'); }

var run = (() => {
    var fns = {
        stuff:  { run: doStuff,  stop: stopStuff  },
        things: { run: doThings, stop: stopThings },
        it:     { run: doIt,     stop: stopIt     },
        "this": { run: doThis,   stop: stopThis   },
        that:   { run: doThat,   stop: stopThat   }
    };
    return what => Object.keys(fns)
        // include the sort only if you need to stop all first before start
        // change a == what to b == what to start selected and then stop the rest
        .sort((a,b) => a == what) 
        .forEach(key => fns[key][what == key ? 'run' : 'stop']());
})();

console.log('things');
run('things');
console.log('this');
run('this');
```

Comment: Thank you. This made the most sense to me and worked perfectly for my use-case! Bonus points for ES6 (before you removed it).

Comment: I can put ES6 back

Comment: @daveycroqet - I've put the ES6 back into the second version (which I think is actually more universal) - added `.sort` to  stop all, then start selected

Answer (score 2):

```
function doStuff()  { console.log('doing stuff'); }
function doThings() { console.log('doing things'); }
function doIt()     { console.log('doing it'); }
function doThis()   { console.log('doing this'); }
function doThat()   { console.log('doing that'); }

function stopStuff()  { console.log('stopping stuff'); }
function stopThings() { console.log('stopping things'); }
function stopIt()     { console.log('stopping it'); }
function stopThis()   { console.log('stopping this'); }
function stopThat()   { console.log('stopping that'); }

var what = 'things';

var doing = {
    stuff:   doStuff,
    things:  doThings,
    it:      doIt,
    this:   doThis,
    that:   doThat  
};

var stopping = {
    stuff:   stopStuff,
    things:  stopThings,
    it:      stopIt,
    this:    stopThis,
    that:    stopThat 
};

var a = Object.keys(stopping);
a.splice(a.indexOf(what), 1);
Object.keys(stopping).map(function(key) {
   return stopping[key]();
});
doing[what]();
```

Comment: nicer than mine in many ways - though `stuff:  function() { doStuff();}` can be `stuff: doStuff` for the win :p

Comment: Both your answer and Jaromanda's fit pretty nicely. I honestly wish I could give you both credit. I wonder whose is more efficient. Regardless, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple for loop as in the following code

> If all your do/stop functions are global - this works

```
for(var idx in doing) {
    if(idx == what) {
        doing[idx]();
    }
    else {
       var fn = idx.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + idx.slice(1);
       var fname = "stop"+fn;
       window[fname]();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let the functions take a parameter, and iterate through an array of functions that call each of them except the parameter. Example:

```
var doing = [
  stuff:  function(func) { 
    stopping.forEach(element => {
      if (element !== func) {
        element()
      }
    }
    doStuff()
  },
  ...
];

var stopping = [
  stopStuff:  function() { stoppingStuff() },
  ...
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Two way you can do it depending on the running a extra function cost.

1. Call all the stop function before starting a new do function.
2. OR filter the particular stop function.

   ```
               function doStuff() {
               console.log('doing stuff');
           }

           function doThings() {
               console.log('doing things');
           }

           function doIt() {
               console.log('doing it');
           }

           function doThis() {
               console.log('doing this');
           }

           function doThat() {
               console.log('doing that');
           }

           function stopStuff() {
               console.log('stopping stuff');
           }

           function stopThings() {
               console.log('stopping things');
           }

           function stopIt() {
               console.log('stopping it');
           }

           function stopThis() {
               console.log('stopping this');
           }

           function stopThat() {
               console.log('stopping that');
           }

           var what = 'things';

           var doing = {
               stuff: function() {
                   doStuff();
               },
               things: function() {
                   doThings();
               },
               it: function() {
                   doIt();
               },
               this: function() {
                   doThis();
               },
               that: function() {
                   doThat();
               }
           };

           var stopping = {
               stuff: function() {
                   stopStuff();
               },
               things: function() {
                   stopThings();
               },
               it: function() {
                   stopIt();
               },
               this: function() {
                   stopThis();
               },
               that: function() {
                   stopThat();
               }
           };

           var stopKeys = Object.keys(stopping);

           function stopsOthers(doing) {
               arr = stopKeys.filter(function(item) {
                   return item !== doing;
               });
               arr.forEach(function(key) {
                   stopping[key]();
               });
           }
           stopsOthers(what);
           doing[what]();
   ```

Comment: @JaromandaX No I have updated fiddle works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/8xjy8gax/1/